# Playing Kodi without UPnP

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, kodi

I have installed latest version of Kodi on a Raspberry Pi 4 with a Raspberry Pi OS. I have plugged in a USB stick and added that as media source of Movies. But I can't play those movies from other devices on my network.

To play media using Kodi, I installed Kodi software on Windows (and Android) and enabled UPnP support on the application, then I added Kodi (on RPi which had storage plugged in) as source of media in Kodi in Windows (and Android). Then I was able to play the media files on my devices.

Honestly, seems a bit more for a client! I mean, technically client will have to enable UPnP support in their devices to play media. Shouldn’t it be like, I add media files to my Kodi Library and client plays those media without enabling UPnP support?

Is this the correct process?

Comment: I couldn't get Kodi to work on my Pi4 using the Raspberry Pi OS, I ended up using the LibreELEC minimal OS and that works fine

Comment: I see, can you please tell me which problem did you face?

Comment: It wouldn't even start

Comment: @Bra1n, I don't think what I am facing is due to the Pi OS. Can you please tell me, did you play your media files stored in your Pi in any other devices in the same network? If yes, how?

Comment: The library which I have in my Kodi(on RPi) needs to be shared right? So, is there really any way without UPnP?

Comment: Besides, I really don't think what you are pointing is what I am asking for. I just installed LibreELEC on another microSD card and what I face is Raspberry Pi OS also exists here.

Comment: Kodi is meant as a client to view media not share it. If you want a central library from which you can use kodi on any device to watch from then you need a nas to store the files centrally and then point kodi at the nas. Kodi will require setting up on each device. If you want a simpler system perhaps something like plex would suit your needs.

Comment: @rohtua, I see. Actually, I have tried previously with Plex. I don't know why Plex fails to download required codec. Here's my [post](https://forums.plex.tv/t/a-required-codec-could-not-be-found-or-failed-to-install/624923) on the plex forum.

Comment: Ahh, I don't really know much about plex to be honest, I've only tried it once or twice. I use the nas + kodi method. Its not ideal but if you did want to go down the kodi route, you can setup one copy of kodi and then copy the .kodi folder to other devices with kodi installed to save re-entering the same sources over and over but you'd need to look up where that folder is for the particular device. On a pi by default it should be in /home/pi/.kodi (if I remember rightly).

Comment: @rohtua, umm, can you please tell me if I create a NAS on my Raspberry Pi then what I will have to do the play the media files on a device which is on the same network of my Pi. Earlier you said, "Kodi will require setting up on each device", what type of setup? Configuring the NAS? can't it be something like click and go?

Comment: Look into openmediavault. Its probably the simplest way to get started with a nas if youre unsure (https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/28789-Installing-OMV5-on-Raspberry-PI-s-Armbian-Supported-SBC-s/) once thats set up you can then add the nas in kodi using the add network location option when adding sources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112682/discussion-between-hasan-and-rohtua).